# Printing a null pointer with printf gives (nil) but printing &ptr gives an address. Why?

Tags: c, pointers

So if I do:

```
int *ptr = NULL:

printf("%p", ptr);
```

I get (nil) printed out. So this is printing out the address of the pointer? Which points to a null pointer address.

but if I do:

```
int *ptr = NULL;

printf("%p", &ptr);
```

I get a memory address. Why is this? Is it because it's giving where the actual NULL memory location is? Does this location always change? I keep getting different memory addresses whenever I use the second piece of code.

Comment: `int ptr = NULL` is not a pointer. It is an integer.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Sorry! Forgot the *. Thanks!

Comment: Which variant of `printf()` gives `(nil)` when printing a null pointer with `%p`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What do you mean which variant?

Comment: Which platform are you running on?  It isn't macOS, for example (that has a different annoying behaviour when printing null pointers with `%p`); but which platform is it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh I am running on a cloud9 machine and `lsb_release -a` shows ubuntu 14.04 Trusty.

Comment: Thanks.  That's interesting.  Don't get used to `(nil)`; it isn't what's printed most places.  On Macs, you get 0x0 (even if you use `%12p`, though it is right-justified in 12 spaces), for example.  And then there are the platforms that don't crash when you use `"%s"` and give it a null pointer to work with...they're apt to print out `(null)` or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *value* stored in the pointer `ptr` is `NULL` or `0`.

However, `ptr` is a variable. It is stored in some memory location. So if you take `&ptr` you will get the memory location that `ptr` is stored in.

Comment: So the %p prints the value of the value of `ptr` if you don't have `&ptr`? Does that only do that if `ptr` is null?

Comment: `printf("%p", ptr);` prints the value in `ptr`. Whatever is the value in `ptr`. e.g. you can do `int a; ptr = &a;` and then `printf("%p", ptr)`. You will get a value there.

Comment: So so in the same scenario, if you do `printf("%p", ptr);` then it would get an address like `0x7ffdf4d5c054` and then if you also do `printf("%p", &ptr);` it gives an address next to it at `0x7ffdf4d5c058`. Is that because because the first one has the address of the a variable inside it and the second one is the actual address of the pointer itself?

Comment: Correct. And if you do `printf("%p", &a)` it will be the same as that for `ptr`